# how can i see all the tweets in my website

Tags: language-agnostic

I m using twitter home page using twitter Api in my local website in which tweets send by own is shown but all the tweets send by any other person are not visible...
how can i see all the tweets in my website in local machine...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @michael, he means when he tweet its working but i cant see others tweet on his embedded page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its **not about web development**.

he is saying in his local machine.
when he login to twitter website, he can see his tweet but cant see others tweet on same page.

if thats the case check faq page

- http://support.twitter.com/entries/13920-frequently-asked-questions